# Data type mismatch in foxpro stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, foxpro

I want to make a copy of every record inserted in **jobact** to a new table **jobactupdates**. I am using a stored procedure for this purpose. Both tables are exactly the same and have same no of columns.  When I insert data in **jobact** using insert query then, the stored procedure fails and show the Data Type mismatch error.

My code looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE insertData

INSERT INTO jobactupdates (jobcode ,jobdescr ,fileno ,port ,mastcode ,mastdescr ,mastdescr1 ,shipper ,goods ,unit1 ,qty ,unit ,vesname ,arremarks ,arrdate ,remarks ,docstat ,docdate ,blno ,bldate ,jastat ,rate ,demand ,received ,balance ,transpor,dldate);

VALUES(jobact.jobcode,jobact.jobdescr,jobact.fileno,jobact.port,jobact.mastcode,jobact.mastdescr,jobact.mastdescr1,jobact.shipper,jobact.goods,jobact.unit1,jobact.qty,jobact.unit,jobact.vesname,jobact.arremarks,jobact.arrdate,jobact.remarks,jobact.docstat,jobact.docdate,jobact.blno,jobact.bldate,jobact.jastat,jobact.rate,jobact.received,jobact.balance,jobact.transpor,jobact.dldate);

ENDPROC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Data Type Mismatch error occurs when you try to insert an inappropriate data type into a field. For example, if you try to store a string into an integer field.  I would double check the table structures and confirm that they are identical.

Another thing to be aware of is if any of the JOBACT field types are set to Integer (AutoInc).  They will have to be set to just Integer in the JOBACTUPDATES table.  Otherwise you will get a "Field  is read-only" error message.

Answer (score 0):

For 
Character fields: write them into `''` marks,
Numeric fields: just numbers for example 123,
Date fields: `{^yyyy-mm-dd}`
(There can also optionally be time in Date field.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual query? If so, the fact your Columns and Values clauses contain different field lists has certainly caused this error:

```
Insert Into ...
bldate,
jastat,
rate,
demand,
received,
balance ..

Values ...
jobact.bldate, 
jobact.jastat,
jobact.rate, 
jobact.received, <--
jobact.balance,  <--
jobact.transpor  <--
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I use an old DOS FOXPRO development kit to pinpoint invalid datum in a DBF file. I found no other editor that does this.

I operate FOXPRO within a DOSBOX. Here is the command line in my desktop icon:

F:\DBF\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe f:\DBF\fpd26

This is my private reminder file how to operate:

F:\DBF\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe

mount C f:\DBF\fpd26

mount d g:\change.mat\DATA...

c:

fox.exe

use d:\TABLE...

brow

list to d:\stam.lst

Using any text editor, find ** in d:\stam.lst

return to fox:

use d:\TABLE

goto [record number]

brow

replace ** with value

Files are SAVED at Fox QUIT
CTL F10 to free cursor